# Finding my ConnectionString in .NET Core integration tests

Tags: c#, integration-testing, .net-core

I'm building automated integration tests for my .NET Core project. Somehow I need to get access to a connection string for my integration tests database. The new .net core no longer has the ConfigurationManager, instead configurations are injected, but there is no way (at least not that I know of) to inject the connection string to a test class.

Is there any way in .NET Core that I can get at the configuration file without injecting something into a test class? Or, alternatively, is there any way that a test class can have dependencies injected into them?

Comment: Could you be more specific? See [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html) for configuration help in Core 1.0.

Comment: I'm not sure what's not clear. Essentially I have a class that needs configuration from a file. The class is running as a plug-in to a framework (the test runner) that I don't control. Because I don't control the framework I can't inject an IOptions<T> into my class to get access to the configuration file. How do I get configuration data in a test class?

Comment: Something like [this](http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2016/02/22/moq-on-net-core)?

Comment: No, I'm already using a mocking framework for my unit tests. This is for an integration test that has to go right through the database.

Comment: Did you figure out a workable approach Jeff? If so consider answering your own question.

Comment: Please see my answer, it's not pretty but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.NET Core 2.0**

Create a new configuration and specify the correct path for your appsettings.json.

This is a part of my TestBase.cs which I inherit in all my tests.

```
public abstract class TestBase
{
    protected readonly DateTime UtcNow;
    protected readonly ObjectMother ObjectMother;
    protected readonly HttpClient RestClient;

    protected TestBase()
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        var connectionStringsAppSettings = new ConnectionStringsAppSettings();
        configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").Bind(connectionStringsAppSettings);

        //You can now access your appsettings with connectionStringsAppSettings.MYKEY

        UtcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
        ObjectMother = new ObjectMother(UtcNow, connectionStringsAppSettings);
        WebHostBuilder webHostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder();
        webHostBuilder.ConfigureServices(s => s.AddSingleton<IStartupConfigurationService, TestStartupConfigurationService>());
        webHostBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        TestServer testServer = new TestServer(webHostBuilder);
        RestClient = testServer.CreateClient();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution.  `appsettings.json` will get checked into your source control, meaning your connection strings and settings will be in source control, something you should avoid.

Comment: @Jez do you have a better solution? Perhaps configure it to use env vars instead of appsettings?

Comment: @Jez Why do you assume you have to check in your secrets to source? You can easily replace values in your devops pipeline or use a connectionstring that doesnt require any protection, (memorydb or similiar). You can also git ignore this file and create it on the fly