# Getting database connection string in .NET Core integration tests with xunit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, xunit.net

I'm doing integration tests for my .net core project.I need to get access to a connection string for my integration tests database.

I am using my base project as reference and using its Startup file. But I am getting this error

```
System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: connectionString at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String 
value, String parameterName) in 
/home/roji/projects/EFCore.PG/src/EFCore.PG/Utilities/Check.cs:line 99   
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.NpgsqlDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseNpgsql(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 npgsqlOptionsAction) in /home/roji/projects/EFCore.PG/src/EFCore.PG/Extensions/NpgsqlDbContextOptionsExtensions.cs:line 49
at SurveyAPI.Startup.<ConfigureServices>b__4_1(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
```

My TestClientProvider class

```
public class TestClientProvider
{
    public HttpClient Client { get; private set; }

    public TestClientProvider()
    {   
        var server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());

        Client = server.CreateClient();
    }
}
```

the test class

```
public class UnitTest1
{

    [Fact]
    public async Task Test_Get()
    {
        var client = new TestClientProvider().Client;

        var response = await client.GetAsync("/api");

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode); 
    }
}
```

How to make the tests use my current database ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding my ConnectionString in .NET Core integration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577095/finding-my-connectionstring-in-net-core-integration-tests)

Comment: @jmdon no this didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by getting the appsettings.json file and configuring the database connection in TestProvider class.

```
public class TestClientProvider
{
    public HttpClient Client { get; private set; }

    public TestClientProvider()
    {   
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        WebHostBuilder webHostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder();
        webHostBuilder.ConfigureServices(s => s.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))));
        webHostBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();

        var server = new TestServer(webHostBuilder);

        Client = server.CreateClient();
    }
}
```

Comment: It could have been an answer to the other question but this is the working solution.